# How to parse Solr facet results in c#

Tags: xml, solr

The following is the partial xml results that is being returned by a Solr query.  I am able to parse the XML and see the data I am interested in InnerXml but not sure how to capture the "cheap,average,expensive" data in separate variables in c#

```
<lst name="price">
  <int name="cheap">3</int>
  <int name="average">4</int>
  <int name="expensive">9</int>
</lst>
```

The following is the complete facet xml code:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_queries"/>
    <lst name="facet_fields"/>
    <lst name="facet_dates"/>
    <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
    <lst name="facet_intervals">
            <lst name="price">
                <int name="cheap">3</int>
                <int name="average">4</int>
                <int name="expensive">9</int>
            </lst>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Comment: Posting an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help others to better help you.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet)? You can also use `&wt=json` to get the results back as JSON and then deserialize JSON in C# to get a easily used data structure back.

Comment: will look into it - thanks.  I am a newbie to the solr world.

Comment: I am playing with my first SolrNet program and have run into a roadblock. I am getting the error when I run the application: "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code".

Comment: complete code here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50644166/edit